# Power Query (PowerBI) Resolving a many to many relationship

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have two contacts tables from two sources which I need to relate:

| ID | email | Last Name | Given Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | angry@mad.com | Thompson | Susan |
| 1 | angry@mad.com | Thompson | Suzanne |
| 2 | glad@mad.com | McNeil | George |
| 3 | happy@sad.com | Thompson | Suzannne |

| Code | Last Name | Given Name | Date Started |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65432 | Thompson | Susan | 2020/01/01 |
| 65432 | Thompson |  | 2019/01/01 |
| 65432 |  | Susan | 2018/01/01 |
| 65432 |  |  | 2017/01/01 |
| 65432 | Thompson | Suzanne | 2016/01/01 |
| 45678 | McNeil | George | 2020/06/20 |
| 45678 | McNeil |  | 2019/06/20 |
| 45678 |  | George | 2018/06/20 |
| 45678 |  |  | 2017/06/20 |
| 25581 | Thompson | Suzanne | 2020/01/01 |

I need a way to link the ID from Table 1 to the Code in Table 2. However, the only common thread between the two tables is the employee's name, which is a many to many relationship and I have no way of knowing which employee is which.

Both tables are prone to human error where multiple name spellings or omissions occur for the same person. However, it is possible to identify that in table 1, the email address is unique to each person (ID 0 and 1 are the same person because they use the same email address) while in table 2, the code is unique to each person (all entries with code 65432 is the same person, etc)

But I am at a complete and total loss on how to create the unique keys I need for each table to link them together.

I was thinking that for table 1, a unique key can be made consisting of the name + email address but I'm stuck there.

Any ideas?

Comment: In table 2, dates are also not same for a single id. What you are thinking about them?

Answer (score 0):

**In table 1:** You can think about group by email and keep MIN/MAX value from other columns. Remember, this will provide you some close to correct results but not correct every time. But this way, you will finally have 1 single email and id/last name/first name in each row.

**In table 2:** you can apply the same as above with a Group by on Code column. This will also move some redundant data (lofically) and give you data in better way.

**In table 2:** You also need to decide first which Date you wants to keep, MAX or MIN per code?

**Finally,** the big issue, how you wants to join table 1 and 2. the only option I can see the First name and Last name columns. But no guaranty you can join all exactly as there are human error in the name spelling.

Answer (score 0):

I have named your first table `tbl1` and the second `tbl2`. In Power Query I performed the following steps to make table `email_vs_code`.

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(tbl1, {"Last Name", "Given Name"}, tbl2, {"Last Name", "Given Name"}, "tbl2", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded tbl2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "tbl2", {"Code"}, {"Code"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded tbl2",{"ID", "Last Name", "Given Name"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

[image: email_vs_code]

Then you can create these relations:
[image: relations]

Then you can see results from `tbl1` and `tbl2` in one table:
[image: results in one table after joining]

After enabling `Show items with no data` the table would look like this:
[image: Show items with no data]

Since "Suzanne" and "Suzannne" are different and the email "happy@sad.com" does not appear anywhere else, the computer cannot know if that is the same person or not. Anyway, this is as close as I can get you to.

There is an issue that we can see in the pictures: names appear several times for the same date if different names exist. You must decide and put somewhere the names which you believe are correct. One name per email.